# make: flex: Command not found

Tags: c, makefile, flex-lexer

When i make some opensource project, there is one error: make: flex: Command not found

I want to know what is the flex ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Flex](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/) is the Fast Lexical analyzer generator.